# gzip for 64-bit Windows

Tags: compression, gzip, gz

Does anyone know any version of Gzip which supports 64-bit Windows? I could not find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "supports"? The 32-bit version of Gzip should run just fine on 64-bit versions of Windows. There is no need for a 64-bit specific version of Gzip.

Comment: when I use GZIP in 64-bit Windows, I receive this message:
the program "GZIP.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to work with gzip files on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I was looking for a command-line GZIP. I did not know that 7-zip has it. I found it now with your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Winrar will open gzip file, they have 64 bit and 32 bit versions here: http://www.win-rar.com/download.html

Comment: Actually, I needed to compress (not decompress) files. I do not think winrar can do Gzip compression.
Thanks